# two interface with the same network configurations

Tags: networking, network-interface, subnets, net

Is it possible to have two interfaces (eth0, eth1) that are connected to different networks but the same IP configurations? For example:

```
NETWORK0 (10.0.0.1/24) <---> eth0 (10.0.0.100/24)
eth1 (10.0.0.100/24) <---> NETWORK1 (10.0.0.1/24)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not specific to Unix/Linux. It should be asked on SuperUser instead, where it is on topic.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Will it work? Probably no. Without the actual problem (example: two same usb cameras creating an Ethernet interface when plugged in and configuring the host via DHCP using the same address) this question doesn't make much sense.